# Fragment not work when actionbar activity start in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

hello i am implement list view in action bar activity when first time it is start but it is not work

i have tried below code but it is not working for me i have just started the learn actionbar

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
     * navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
     * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        Fragment fr=new FragmentOne();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fr);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments



    }


    public void restoreActionBar() {


        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


            private String[] mStrings={
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image0.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image1.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image2.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image3.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image4.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image5.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image6.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image7.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image8.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image9.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image10.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image0.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image1.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image2.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image3.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image4.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image5.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image6.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image7.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image8.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image9.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image10.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image0.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image1.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image2.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image3.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image4.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image5.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image6.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image7.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image8.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image9.png",
                    "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image10.png"

            };

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentone,container,false);

            }


            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                ListView listview=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);

                  // Create custom adapter for listview
                LazyImageLoadAdapter adapter=new LazyImageLoadAdapter(getActivity(), mStrings);

                //Set adapter to listview
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Share more information please: for example logs, what is the exception etc. At first sight, I see that you should commit your fragment transaction in your onCreate method. Fix it, this could be one reason ;)

Comment: not getting your point commit means ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean: fragmentManager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fr). **commit();** Please don't forget to attach more information about the error in order to make it easier

Comment: just one question current FragmentOne() class is in the same activity if i declare this class out side of the activity means as a new class than it gives me error  Fragment fr=new FragmentOne(); convert fr to FragmentOne() and if i convert fr to Fragmentone() than fragmentManager .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fr).commit(); in this replace give me error change fr to fragment what should i do if i want touse fragmenone() out side of activity

Comment: I would try removing the static qualifier of the class. I use fragments from external classes without problems. If this does not work, tell me and we can try something else.

I'll post it as an answer. Please, don't forget accept the answer an vote up please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit the transaction!

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fr).commit();
```